# Error in SQLite3 foreigin or foreign

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a db in sqlite3 version 3.9.2, and if I add a new field on table, return syntax error. ex:

```
alter table table_01 add column tab_2 integer foreign key references table_02(id);
// this command return syntax error.
alter table table_01 add column tab_2 integer foreigin key references table_02(id);
// and this return success.
```

can someone say why this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second command create a column with the (rather nonsensical) type `integer foreigin key`. This is due to [SQLite being lax about data types](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html); the resulting column will have integer affinity.

The [correct syntax for adding a new column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) with a foreign key does not have `FOREIGN KEY` at all:

```
ALTER TABLE table_01 ADD COLUMN tab_2 INTEGER REFERENCES table_02(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to specify "foreign key" at all in that. I imagine the latter works because it is not a keyword and reads it as the name of the column.

Also, you should be providing a data type following the column name.

Comment: sorry, I write wrong. the command is `alter table table_01 add column tab_2 integer foreigin key references table_02(id);`

Comment: You shouldn't need to type "foreign/foreigin key" at all.